# Convert List<string> to List<DateTime>

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Example of a list that need to be converted

```
List<string> dateStrings = new List<string>(new string[]
        {
            "11/15 8:00 AM",
            "1/5 9:00 PM"
        }
```

I tried to convert with the help of DateTime.ParseExact() but the problem is that mm/dd format is not consistent.

```
Date dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateStrings[0], "MM/dd h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: also, the array is redundant `new List<string>(new string[]` when you can just use  `new List<string>(){...}`

Answer (score 2):

You can LINQ to iterate over the list.

```
        List<string> dateStrings = new List<string>(new string[]
        {
            "11/15 8:00 AM",
            "1/5 9:00 PM"
        });



        var newDates = dateStrings
            .Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x, "M/d h:m tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            .Cast<DateTime>();


        foreach(var dd in newDates)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dd);
```

Comment: You don't need to cast after the select.

Comment: Also, `Select` is an `IEnumerable<T>`. For `List<T>`, you need to call `ToList` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
                    dateStrings[0],
                    "M/d h:m tt",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Try it online](http://rextester.com/QZKBF7006)

It will accept single-digit and double-digit numbers for month, day, hour, and minute.

You might also considering switching to `TryParseExact` which will return `true` if it was able to parse the date/time and then provides the date parameter as an `out` argument. In contrast, a straight `ParseExact` would throw an exception if it can't parse the date.

```
DateTime dateTime;
string dateString = "5/11 10:00 am";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
            dateString,
            "M/d h:m tt",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out dateTime))
{
    // yay
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to "map" every `string` to `DateTime`. You do this with `Select` method and this operation is called "Projection".

[Documentation on LINQ Projection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/projection-operations)

### Using directives

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
```

### Extension method

[Documentation on extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

**Note**: `ParseExact` throws an exception if it cannot parse the string. If you don't know if the list items are always valid, you should use `TryParseExact` instead.

**Note 2**: You can remove the `this` keyword to make it a normal method.

```
public static List<DateTime> MapToDateTimes(this List<string> dateTimeStrings, string format = "M/d h:mm tt")
{
    IEnumerable<DateTime> mapped = dateTimeStrings
        .Select(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

    return mapped.ToList();
}
```

### Calling the method

```
List<string> dateStrings = new List<string>()
{
    "11/15 8:00 AM",
    "1/5 9:00 PM"
};

List<DateTime> datesList = dateStrings.MapToDateTimes();
```